# A right angle triangle has sides $a,b,c$ ($a,b,c$ are integers).Can its area be perfect square??

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I was trying to solve by taking one side $a=z(x^2+y^2)$, $b=2xyz$,
$c=z(x^2-y^2)$. And I determined the area.  Am I going right? Will this help me anyway?

Comment: If the right triangle has legs $a$ and $b$ and hypotenuse $c$, the right parameterization is $a=z\left(x^2-y^2\right)$, $b=2xyz$, and $c=z\left(x^2+y^2\right)$. And yes, this will help.

Comment: Might as well assume $z=1$ and $x$ and $y$ are coprime.  Obvious $ka, kb, kc$ yield a perfect square area if and only if $a,b, c$ do.

Comment: By the way, the answer to this question was one of the few things proven by Fermat. (In fact, his proof implied Fermat's last theorem for $n=4$.)

Comment: The area can not be a perfect square. It's the Fermat's known result. Prove that the equation $x^4+y^2=z^4$ has no solutions in natural ($\geq1$) numbers.

Comment: It's not easy to solve this question on your own. A familiarity with proof by descent is helpful.